# HTML Tables not accepting width

Tags: google-chrome, html-table, html-email

http://www.trileafweb.com/email.html

Why will these TD tags toward the bottom not accept my width of 300px? I cannot understand it for the life of me :/

I will put width="300px" on it and then go to inspect element it says its got a width of 255px instead... I hate tables...

I am using tables for layout because it's going into emails as a newsletter of sorts. It's becoming a huge pain.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using tables for layout purposes? If it's just because it's the only way you half know, start half knowing about table-less layouts.

Comment: Probably because the the max table cell per row is 3 and you're trying to divide the table by 2. A hack but not advised is make the last row with a single `<td colspan=3>` and create a table with only two cells within that with `width=300`

Comment: are you refering to the table that has services and results?

Comment: Why are you using tables for non-tabular data (there are many arguments against doing so including load speed of the page)? Tr's shouldn't have a width on them as they take up the width of the table. When you specify the width of the table it should be done in the CSS not as an attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the rows above you have 3 columns. This is causing the issue. You need to set one column of the 2-column rows to `colspan="2"`

Comment: What's the point of a width attribute if you have to manage it through colspans?

Comment: You have to manage both width and colspans when you have a varying number of columns across your rows. If yout table had 3 columns in every row, you would really only have to set the width in the first two columns of the first row (or header), and the rest would follow suit. Since you are mixing it up a little you have to be more specific.